# PHP Regex: How to match the word before dash?

Tags: php, regex

Here's my code, but it's not working. How can I match the word before dash?

```
$str = '-Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy- text of the printing';
preg_match('/(.*)\-/', $str, $matches);
```

**Expected Output:** dummy

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Match word without a capture group, then require that it is followed by a hyphen `/\w+(?=-)/`. A lookahead does not consume/match characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match('/(\S+)-/', $str, $matches);

echo ($matches[1] ?? null);
```

The `\S` means "Any non-whitespace character". So it's kind of like saying "Match one or more non-whitespace characters up to a hyphen."

Test it out at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/E3gOqm/1

Comment: The square braces are not necessary and are bloating the output array.  The hyphen does not need to be escaped.